# jQuery masonry plugin not being activated

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to implement the jquery masonry images plugin, it seems to be setup right, but it's not working!

I debugged using my browser, and didn't see any errors.

What could I be doing wrong? Code is below. Thanks. Faisal

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
<style>
.item {
 width: 200px;
.... }

</style>
<div id="container">
<div class="item">
....
</div>

<script>
$(function(){
    var $container = $('#container');
    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
      $container.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.tile',
        columnWidth : 240
      });
    });
});
</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I can see from your code is this line:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You haven't added a "http:" to the beginning of your link to your jQuery file. Shouldn't it be:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Can you upload a jsFiddle version of your page?

Comment: Here is the jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/UcWtg/ . I'm using bootstrap for styling.